# Problem when trying to access struct object inside of array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, abstract-data-type

I am having trouble trying to push an element into my queue and I cannt figure out what is wrong. I have an own-defined data type and I am pretty sure I am not trying to acces memory that has not been allocated or any other such-related scenarios.

**Queue.h**

```
typedef int TElem
//...
struct NodeDLLA {
TElem data;
int prev;
int next;
};

class Queue
{
//...
}
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
Queue::Queue() {
cap = 105;
len = 0;

head = -1;
tail = -1;

NodeDLLA* nodes = new NodeDLLA[cap];

nodes[0].prev = -1;                 
nodes[0].next = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < cap - 1; i++)
{
    nodes[i].prev = i - 1;
    nodes[i].next = i + 1;
}
nodes[cap - 1].prev = cap - 2;
nodes[cap - 1].next = -1;           

firstEmpty = 0; 

}
void Queue::push(TElem elem) {

    if (firstEmpty == -1)
    {
        //resize array...
    }

    cout << "check\n";
    cout << firstEmpty <<'\n';
    nodes[firstEmpty].data = elem; // here is the problem.
    cout << "check2\n";        
    // "check" is shown in the console terminal, but "check2" is not. 
    // firstEmpty is zero, thus there should be no problem of trying to access "illegal memory area"
    // ... rest of code
}
```

**ShortTest.cpp**

```
#include "ShortTest.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
void testAll() {
    Queue q;
    assert(q.isEmpty() == true);
    q.push(5);
    cout << "So far so good" << '\n';
    /*
    q.push(1);
    q.push(10);
    assert(q.isEmpty() == false);
    assert(q.top() == 5);
    assert(q.pop() == 5);
    assert(q.top() == 1);
    assert(q.pop() == 1);
    assert(q.top() == 10);
    assert(q.pop() == 10);
    assert(q.isEmpty() == true);
    */
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "ShortTest.h"
int main()
{
      testAll();
      return 0;   
}
```

Console output:

```
check
```

Expected output:

```
check
check2
So far so good
```

Comment: Insufficient data for meaningful answer. Show a [mcve]

Comment: It's not a [mcve]. It doesn't even show what `nodes` is. What makes you believe `nodes[firstEmpty]` is valid?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik indeed, sorry for that! Out of rush, my bad. Now it should be ok.

Comment: What's the point of `prev` and `next` members in the node class? You are using a dynamically allocated *array* to store the nodes.

Comment: `NodeDLLA* nodes = new NodeDLLA[cap];` This declares and initializes a local variable named `nodes`. Presumably, there's a data member also named `nodes` - it remains uninitialized. Any access to it then exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: cout << firstEmpty <<'\n'; is also not executed.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik! And sorry for not posting everything that had to be posted all at once. Furthermore, yes nodes is a `NodeDLLA*` type member of my Queue class. That was the problem. I did not need to re-declare the nodes in the .cpp. This solved my problem. Silly mistake... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you for commenting! The container (not sure if I am using "container" here, in this case, correctly) that I am using to implement my Queue is DLLA ( Dynamically Linked Lists on Arrays). Basically I am not using pointers from one element to the other, but I am simulating this by using two index arrays that store the indexes of the previous, respectively the following node. Not sure if I answered your question here...

Comment: @dj1986 Thank you for commenting! It did execute for me. Nonetheless, my problem is solved now.

Comment: @M.Ioan Sounds good. It will be better if you explain the prob and solution in you post edit.

Comment: I see. Consider using a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6X6yXvT9uI).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments&suggestions!